# Python 3 DictWriter csv BytesIO TypeError

Tags: python, string, csv, python-3.x, encoding

I'm using python 3 trying to generate a csv on the file.
I want to ensure that I'm writing utf8 so I'm converting values of my list of dicts into byte strings

```
field_order = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
stats = ... # list of dicts
output = io.BytesIO()
writer = csv.DictWriter(output, field_order)
writer.writeheader()
for stats in my_stats:
    writer.writerow({k: bytes(v, 'utf8') for k, v in stats.items()})
    csv_output = output.getvalue()
```

I'm getting an exception on the writer.writeheader() call

```
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

There doesn't seem to any way to change writerheader to write bytes.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

`csv` mdoule operates on strings according to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects):

> Writer objects (DictWriter instances and objects returned by the
>   writer() function) have the following public methods. A row must be a
>   sequence of **strings** or numbers for Writer objects and a dictionary
>   mapping fieldnames to strings or numbers (by passing them through
>   str() first) for DictWriter objects. Note that complex numbers are
>   written out surrounded by parens. This may cause some problems for
>   other programs which read CSV files (assuming they support complex
>   numbers at all).

How about using `io.StringIO`, and later encode it `utf-8`.

```
import csv
import io

field_order = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4']
my_stats = ...
output = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.DictWriter(output, field_order)
writer.writeheader()
for stats in my_stats:
    writer.writerow(stats)
csv_output = output.getvalue().encode('utf-8')
```